# How to setup wpa_supplicant in Buildroot?

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to setup `wpa_supplicant` using Buildroot for one of the project. I am using Buildroot 2022 version and I have selected below config in `menuconfig`

[image: wpa_supplicant]

But after doing `make` I am getting below error:

```
>>> wpa_supplicant 2.10 Installing to staging directory
/usr/bin/install -m 0644 -D /root/raspcm4/sources/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.10/wpa_supplicant/libwpa_client.so /root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libwpa_client.so
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '/root/raspcm4/sources/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.10/wpa_supplicant/libwpa_client.so': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:331: /root/raspcm4/sources/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.10/.stamp_staging_installed] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:23: _all] Error 2
```

There is no `libwpa_client.so` Is there any other packages needs to be selected in Buildr
oot?

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was introduced on Buildroot git master with wpa_supplicant version bump [1](https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/package/wpa_supplicant?id=39381a467cd2cfc15f77d3f9adbf329d2f92e312) and fixed with [2](https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/package/wpa_supplicant?id=c4eebf191c781a3ea6b5eb1811cc17ae92ea2fb2). So, by including patch for wpa_supplicant above issue is solved.

[1]https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/package/wpa_supplicant?id=39381a467cd2cfc15f77d3f9adbf329d2f92e312
[2]https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/package/wpa_supplicant?id=c4eebf191c781a3ea6b5eb1811cc17ae92ea2fb2